# how to make download of different files from one nsurlconnection

Tags: iphone, nsurlconnection

I am having a single file with 5 url to download 5 different files. What I am doing is calling the method which will change the url and make another call to download the file. how should it be ideally ? My requirement is sequential download of file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.. [Custom classes](http://github.com/leonho/iphone-libs) implemented by leonho.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use multiple NSURLConnections. When one download finishes, start the next.

Don't worry about "overhead"; AFAIK NSURLConnection reuses TCP connections where possible.